# mocking a function with jest enzyme runs on screen loading

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

there is a function runs while screen loading. I need to mock the function in order to cover the code. The tests are passed but uncovered status not changed.

> Uncovered line is: else return [];

```
filterPermissionOwner = ownerTypeID => {
    let row = this.props.permissionOwner.payload.filter(item => item.ownerTypeID === ownerTypeID);

    if (row.length > 0) return [row[0].roleUID];
    else return [];
  };

//Unit Test Code : 
it("filterPermissionOwner", () => {
            wrapper = shallow( < PermissionDetail { ...props
                }
                />);
                const instance = wrapper.instance(); instance.filterPermissionOwner = jest.fn().mockImplementation((ownerTypeID) => {
                    return [];
                }); instance.filterPermissionOwner(-1); expect(instance.filterPermissionOwner).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
```

> Expected: else return []; line should be covered.
>
> Actual: line not covered.

Comment: Hi, so from what I can see you are mocking the function here but you are actually trying to evaluate it ? In general your test is not covering anything you create a function, then call it and expect it to be called so actually not testing anything. 
I would suggest don't mock the function actually just call it and cover both cases with different props on your wrapper, you should be able to do `wrapper.instance().filterPermissionOwner(-1)` without mock the actual function and you should be asserting the expected result not the been called.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i covered by below code and it works!. 
`it("filterPermissionOwner", () => {
      wrapper = shallow(<PermissionDetail {...props} />);
      const instance = wrapper.instance();
      instance.filterPermissionOwner(-1);
    });`